# Sound on Push notification

Tags: swift2

Helo friends

I created a code to push nofication, but the notification are silient, I need to use sound,
On this line I specify the types:

```
let notificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert
```

But dont work.
Another dount, How can I use Badge to add number in app icon?

this is my code:

```
func setupNotificationSettings() {  

    let notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings! = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()  

    if (notificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationType.None){  

        let notificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert  

        let modifyListAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()  
        modifyListAction.identifier = "editList"  
        modifyListAction.title = "Edit list"  
        modifyListAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground  
        modifyListAction.destructive = false  
        modifyListAction.authenticationRequired = true  

        let trashAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()  
        trashAction.identifier = "trashAction"  
        trashAction.title = "Delete list"  
        trashAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background  
        trashAction.destructive = true  
        trashAction.authenticationRequired = true  

        let actionsArray = NSArray(objects: modifyListAction, trashAction)  
        let actionsArrayMinimal = NSArray(objects: trashAction, modifyListAction)  

        /  
        let shoppingListReminderCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()  
        shoppingListReminderCategory.identifier = "shoppingListReminderCategory"  
        shoppingListReminderCategory.setActions(actionsArray as? [UIUserNotificationAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)  
        shoppingListReminderCategory.setActions(actionsArrayMinimal as? [UIUserNotificationAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)  


        let categoriesForSettings = NSSet(objects: shoppingListReminderCategory)  


        /  
        let newNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: categoriesForSettings as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)  
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(newNotificationSettings)  
    }  

}  

   func pushNotificationTest(){  
        let localNotification = UILocalNotification()  
        localNotification .fireDate =    fixNotificationDate(datePicker.date) //usar com datepicker  
        localNotification.alertBody = "Test"  
        localNotification.alertAction = "Test test test"  
        localNotification.category = "shoppingListReminderCategory"  

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't request enough permissions. You only requested `.Alert`, but `.Sound` and `.Badge` should all be included. Change:

```
let notificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert
```

to:

```
let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Sound, .Badge]
```

To add a badge number, use:

```
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
```